# Como modificar manera dinámica la propiedad y el valor de un plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Una consulta, estoy construyendo una aplicación con Angular y estoy utilizando un plugin llamado  gaugeMeter.js para crear medidores o indicadores gráficos, dicho plugin utiliza JQuery.
Les pongo un ejemplo de como es el plugin

```html
  <div
  class="temperatura-mx"
  class="GaugeMeter"
  id="PreviewGaugeMeter_1"
  data-percent="12.5"
  data-used="12.5"
  data-total="500"></div>
```

Lo que necesito es modificar de manera dinámica esos valores, pero no me lo permite, ya intente con [attr.] pero no parece funcionar

```html
 <div class="GaugeMeter"
  id="PreviewGaugeMeter_1"
  [attr.data-percent]="gaugePercent"
  [attr.data-used]="gaugePercent">
</div>
```

También ya probé con jQuery pero pues no

```js
$(".temperatura-mx").gaugeMeter({'data-percent': "30" , 'data-used':"30"});
```

¿Qué puedo utilizar para modificar dichos valores?